# How can convert a custom string to number and keep same format

Tags: typescript, number-formatting

I using string for format my number 100000 to 1,00,000. Want to keep same format and convert it string to number. Any suggestion how can i convert it? I am using typescript language.

Comment: A number doesn't have any format. If you want a formatted number, then string is the type you want, and there is nothing to convert. If you want, let's say, multiply that formatted number by 2 and then display the result as a string, then multiply the number by 2, and format the result. In short, use numbers for all your calculations, and only transform them to string when displaying them. Don't store values as strings.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to keep the number as it is (without formatting) for running all operations on the number and then convert the number to the formatted string only for displaying.

If you still want to convert the formatted number (`1,00,0000`) to an integer, you can use the code below.

```
var formattedNumber = "1,00,000";
var number = parseInt(formattedNumber.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
```

If your number contains decimal places use the code below.

```
var formattedNumber = "1,00,000.99";
var number = parseFloat(formattedNumber.replace(/,/g, ''));
```